# Can an American licensee operate in Portugal during a visit?

Tags: united-states, europe

I have an American Amateur Extra Class licence (AC1DM) and I'm going to Portugal for a few days. Can I operate there with my licence? I'm not an American citizen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I operate in the United Kingdom with a US license?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/119/can-i-operate-in-the-united-kingdom-with-a-us-license)

Comment: That question is not addressing the matter of citizenship.

Comment: Yes, and one requirement of operating under the CEPT agreements is that US hams be able to show a US passport upon request. So there is a citizenship requirement. (See here for source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio_international_operation#US_and_Canadian_citizens_visiting_a_CEPT_Country )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the various online sources, it looks like the answer to your question is **no**.

US amateurs can operate in [CEPT countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio_international_operation#CEPT_License), but a requirement is that they be US citizens.

Your user name suggests that you hold a licence in Argentina, but sadly Argentina is not a party to the CEPT agreements.

If your visit is only for a few days, it might not be worth it to try other options. It might be possible to get a reciprocal licence, and if you were resident in Portugal or travelling there often it would be worth considering. But if it’s just for a single trip it might not be feasible.

Comment: That's what I thought. I have citizenships in Argentina and Spain and ham radio licences in Argentina, the US and UK. With all of this, due to the CEPT agreements requiring citizenship, I cannot operate while traveling abroad.

Comment: Aha! The UK is (currently, anyway) still in the EU, and is also a party to the CEPT agreements. If you look on the RSGB (UK national society) website, it does NOT mention citizenship as a requirement: http://rsgb.org/main/operating/licensing-novs-visitors/operating-abroad/

Comment: So you should be able to use your **UK** license in Portugal, under the CEPT agreement.

Comment: Oh, that's good to know. I don't have a full license yet, so, I won't be able to use it in this trip, but early next year I should manage to upgrade all the way to full license.